# how to do multiply-all function in RACKET

Tags: scheme, racket, multiplication

**Exercise 22.5.11** Develop a function multiply-all that takes in a list of numbers and returns the result of multiplying them all together.
*For example:*
`(check-expect (multiply-all (cons 3 (cons 5 (cons 4 empty)))) 60)`
*Hint:* What is the “right answer” for the empty list? It may not be what you think at ﬁrst!

*Solution:* The data deﬁnition is similar to that for list-of-strings:

```
; A list-of-numbers is either
; empty or
; a nelon (non-empty list of numbers).
#|
(define (function-on-lon L)
; L a list of numbers
(cond [ (empty? L) ...]
[ (cons? L) (function-on-nelon L)]
))
|#
; A nelon looks like
; (cons number lon )
#|
(define (function-on-nelon L)
; L a cons
; (first L) a number
; (rest L) a lon
; (function-on-lon (rest L)) whatever this returns
...)
|#
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's really only a small step from `count-numbers` in 22.5 to here (ref: http://picturingprograms.com/download/chap22.pdf)

Comment: i wrote it in other lenguege , i'm trying to learn it , so this is a basic question , from the link http://picturingprograms.com/download/chap22.pdf

Comment: but there are no answers there

Comment: i'm guessing it will be similar to : Worked Exercise 22.5.2 Develop a function add-up that takes in a list of numbers
and returns the result of adding them all together. For example,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the simplest solution, use `apply` for this:

```
(define (multiply-all lst)
  (apply * lst))
```

If you need to build the procedure from scratch, just remember that the base case (an empty list) should return `1`, and the recursive step should multiply the current value using the standard solution template, like this:

```
(define (multiply-all lst)
  (if (empty? lst)
      1
      (* (first lst)
         (multiply-all (rest lst)))))
```

For a nicer answer, you can try using tail recursion:

```
(define (multiply-all lst)
  (let loop ([lst lst] [acc 1])
    (if (empty? lst)
        acc
        (loop (rest lst) (* (first lst) acc)))))
```

Anyway the procedures work as expected:

```
(multiply-all '())
=> 1
(multiply-all '(3 5 4))
=> 60
```

Comment: thanks , base on which code ? the one i placed in the question ?

Comment: in case that i would like to do a square of each number in the list and sum it all together , i've tried to change like this : (let loop([1st 1st] [acc 0]) , and also :  (loop (rest 1st)(*(first 1st) acc))))) , but it didn't return me any number - just true

Comment: @user3433101 answering your question: if you want to square each value, then do so at the point where we access the current element. That is, instead of writing `(first lst)` write `(* (first lst) (first lst))`

Comment: like this :  (loop (rest 1st)(* (first 1st) (first 1st) acc))))) ?

Comment: @user3433101 and why ist it not working? is the output incorrect? what is the expected output? what output did you get? you should post this as a new, separate question, it's a different question

Comment: the problem is that the result is always 0 .

Comment: If one of the numbers in the list is zero, then the result will be zero

Comment: (test (sum-squares '(1 2 3)) => 14)

Comment: Test failures!
  (sum-squares (quote (1 2 3))): expected 14, got 0

Comment: That's a different question! you said you wanted to square each number in `multiply-all`, _not_ that you wanted to add them. Post it a separate question.