# How to do square in RACKET

Tags: scheme, racket

Here is my code:

```
(define (squares 1st)
  (let loop([1st 1st] [acc 0])
    (if (null? 1st)
        acc
        (loop (rest 1st) (* (first 1st) (first 1st) acc)))))
```

My test is:

```
(test (sum-squares '(1 2 3)) => 14 )
```

and it's failed.

The function input is a list of number [1 2 3] for example, and I need to square each number and sum them all together, output - number.
The test will return #t, if the correct answer was typed in.

Comment: The parameter name should be `lst` (shorthand for list), not `1st` (that's "first")

Comment: You don't have a Scheme interpreter?  Or don't have the energy to use one?  It failed by returning '0' no matter what; and you can't find the error?  What was your first guess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is rather similar to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22479897/201359), but with a twist: here we *add*, instead of multiplying. And each element gets squared before adding it:

```
(define (sum-squares lst)
  (if (empty? lst)
      0
      (+ (* (first lst) (first lst))
         (sum-squares (rest lst)))))
```

As before, the procedure can also be written using tail recursion:

```
(define (sum-squares lst)
  (let loop ([lst lst] [acc 0])
    (if (empty? lst)
        acc
        (loop (rest lst) (+ (* (first lst) (first lst)) acc)))))
```

You must realize that both solutions share the same structure, what changes is:

- We use `+` to *combine* the answers, instead of `*`
- We *square* the current element `(first lst)` before adding it
- The base case for adding a list is `0` (it was `1` for multiplication)

As a final comment, in a real application you shouldn't use explicit recursion, instead we would use higher-order procedures for composing our solution:

```
(define (square x)
  (* x x))

(define (sum-squares lst)
  (apply + (map square lst)))
```

Or even shorter, as a one-liner (but it's useful to have a `square` procedure around, so I prefer the previous solution):

```
(define (sum-squares lst)
  (apply + (map (lambda (x) (* x x)) lst)))
```

Of course, any of the above solutions works as expected:

```
(sum-squares '())
=> 0

(sum-squares '(1 2 3))
=> 14
```

Comment: Shouldn't we be careful with apply,as in some implementations it's only accepts a limited number of arguments?

Comment: @WorBlux Or is racket not one of those?

Comment: @WorBlux Racket doesn't have that limitation ;)

Answer (score 4):

A more functional way would be to combine simple functions (`sum` and `square`) with high-order functions (`map`):

```
(define (square x) (* x x))
(define (sum lst) (foldl + 0 lst))

(define (sum-squares lst)
  (sum (map square lst)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Benesh's answer, just modifying it slightly so you don't have to traverse the list twice. (One fold vs a map and fold)

```
(define (square x) (* x x))
(define (square-y-and-addto-x x y) (+  x (square y)))
(define (sum-squares lst) (foldl square-y-and-addto-x 0 lst))
```

Or you can just define map-reduce

```
(define (map-reduce map-f reduce-f nil-value lst)
  (if (null? lst) 
      nil-value
      (map-reduce map-f reduce-f (reduce-f nil-value (map-f (car lst))))))

(define (sum-squares lst) (map-reduce square + 0 lst))
```

Comment: thanks! i still have not learned apply , but thanks anyway . iv'e learned a lot from your help !

Answer (score 0):

```
racket@> (define (f xs) (foldl (lambda (x b) (+ (* x x) b)) 0 xs))
racket@> (f '(1 2 3))
14
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the use of loops or lamdas, `cond` can be used to solve this problem as follows ( printf is added just to make my exercises distinct. This is an exercise from [SICP](https://mitp-content-server.mit.edu/books/content/sectbyfn/books_pres_0/6515/sicp.zip/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html#%25_sec_1.1.4) : exercise 1.3):

```
;; Takes three numbers and returns the sum of squares of two larger number
;; a,b,c -> int
;; returns -> int
(define (sum_sqr_two_large a b c)
  (cond
    ((and (< a b) (< a c)) (sum-of-squares b c))
    ((and (< b c) (< b a)) (sum-of-squares a c))
    ((and (< c a) (< c b)) (sum-of-squares a b))
  )
)

;; Sum of squares of numbers given
;; a,b -> int
;; returns -> int
(define (sum-of-squares a b)
  (printf "ex. 1.3:  ~a \n" (+ (square a)(square b)))
)

;; square of any integer
;; a -> int
;; returns -> int
(define (square a)
  (* a a)
)

;; Sample invocation
(sum_sqr_two_large 1 2 6)
```